# Scringo Login status changes not received on Android

Tags: scringo

I'm trying to implement Scringo Login status change on Android. But my Broadcast receiver is never called.
I've followed the instructions described on http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/popular/handling-login-status-changes/

So I registered my broadcast receiver:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.jino.footster.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.scringo.LoginBroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And I then defined my Broacast receiver:

```
package com.jino.footster;

import com.scringo.utils.ScringoLogger;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("com.scringo.LoginBroadcast")) {
                boolean isLogin = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("isLogin");
                String accountId = intent.getExtras().getString("accountId");
                ScringoLogger.e("Got Login receiver: " + isLogin + ", " + accountId);       
            }
        }
    }
```

When I start the application the login seems to be successful: I see the below message in logcat:

04-24 01:12:35.000: I/Scringo(4717): Your Scringo user token is: a03fgalc5E

However, the onReceive method of my broadcast receiver is never called.

Would someone be able to help?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the category:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.jino.footster.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.scringo.LoginBroadcast" />
            <category android:name="com.jino.footster"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```